# Magento. Use default baseUrl from core_config_data table

Tags: php, magento

I have 3 websites set up with different URLs, say `s1.site.com`, `s2.site.com` and `s3.site.com` and I have default `site.com`. In my `core_config_data` table scopes `websites` and `default`.
Now I need in the admin panel for preview mode magento to load my skins and `css`s not from its own website baseUrl but from default baseUrl from that table.

Let's say I'm in privew mode, I change the store views, I get my different sites, but if I view the source the `js` and `css` files should come from site.com.

I suppose I should point magento to use the default baseUrl from that table. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To include js and css from main website. You should change from admin end

Navigate to System->Configuration, Select Your store And Click "Web" tab in General Configuration

[image]